# Cambiar disposción Imagenes con FPDF PHP

Tags: php, fpdf

actualmente estoy generando un PDF, con 4 columnas y una imagen por cada línea,

```
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 7);
$pdf->Cell(16, 8, '##',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(30, 8, 'Fecha',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(30, 8, 'Loc',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(85, 8, 'Foto',1,0,'C',1);    
$pdf->Ln(12);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);        
while($pro14 = mysql_fetch_array($t14))
{   $item = $item+1;
    $dia = $pro14['mfecha'];
    $tienda =  $pro14['centrocoste'];
    $encargada = $pro14['nombre'];
    $pdf->Cell(16, 8, $item,0,0,'C',0);
    $pdf->Cell(30, 8, fechanormal($pro14['fecha']),0,0,'C',0); 
    $pdf->Cell(30, 8, $pro14['centrocoste'],0,0,'L',0); 
    $pdf->Cell(15, 8, '',0,0,'L',0);
    $pdf->Cell( 47, 52, $pdf->Image($image1.$pro14['foto'], $pdf->GetX(), $pdf->GetY(), 47,52,'JPG'), 1, 1, 'C', false ); 
    $pdf->Ln(2);}
```

ahora necesitaría hacer otro similar, con una fila inicial para los parámetros # , Fecha y  Loc; y luego por debajo que las imágenes se dividiesen en dos columnas con un máximo de 3 imágenes por columna ( 6 por hoja), he estado buscando pero no he encontrado nada que me sirva de guía,
Este es el resultado que tengo ahora

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este sería el resultado que buscaría:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si alguien me puede dar alguna pista, Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? ¿Qué esperas obtener y qué estás obteniendo? ¿Hay algún error? Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: Buenas, he añadido unas imágenes para que sea más sencillo de ver, gracias